# Form submit does not response for iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have facing the challenge in iPhone 6, 6s and 8 mobiles that when the user click the submit button in HTML form, it's does not redirect to another website

```
<form name="online" id="form" action="www.abc.com" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <input type="hidden" name="RETURN_URL" value="example.com/callback">
                    <p class="edgeBox_Outer Adjust04">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" 
                                style="background: none;border: none;color:#fff;font-size: 90%;font-weight: bold; width:100%; " 
                                value ="Submit">
                    </p>
```

Can you please anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: If you have `action="www.abc.com"`, then no, it won't go to another domain, since `www.abc.com` is interpreted as a *relative path*, not a domain. That should be true for all browsers, not just iOS. If you want to refer to a different domain, you need an absolute URI starting with `http://`…

Answer (score 0):

you had left the closing tag of form `</form>`, also you hadn't added `http://` or `https://`, also the submit button and input tag wasn't visible (you can change it later).

But mainly the problem was "not having closed form tag"

```html
<form name="online" id="form" action="https://www.example.com" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="text" name="RETURN_URL" value="example.com/callback">

<p class="edgeBox_Outer Adjust04"><input type="submit" id="submit" style="background: none; border: none; color: red; font-size: 90%;font-weight: bold; width:100%;" value ="Submit"> </p>

</form>
```

Comment: yes. I did that but page is not redirected and this issue only on iPhone

Comment: yes. But its working on android device not on iPhone device that the challenge I am facing now

Comment: that's weird, are you getting any response as why it's not working? are you getting something like "can't open website too many redirects" or something??